# Pause all bindings tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, bind

Is there any possibility to *pause* all bindings on tkinter?? For instance:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry("600x400")
def function(event=None):
    print("Hello world!")

btn = Button(root,text="Click me!")
btn.bind("<Button-1>",function)
btn.pack()

def resume_bindings():
    pass

def pause_bindings():
    pass

root.mainloop()
```

A way could be to call the *btn.bind* method inside *resume_bindings*, but I was looking for something more similar to interruptions. In Arduino, you can activate/desactivate all interruptions with the following:

```
interrupts();
noInterrupts();
```

Is there a method to pause/temporally desactivate all bindings in tkinter? Thanks!

Comment: You can add something like `return None if not bind_enabled` inside the bind callee to just skip the event

Answer (score 0):

There is  a method to pause/temporally desactivate all bindings in tkinter,  works by setting the state of the widgets.

> Buttons and many other widgets start off in a normal state. A button will respond to mouse movements, can be pressed, and will invoke its command callback. Buttons can also be put into a disabled state, where the button is greyed out, does not respond to mouse movements, and cannot be pressed. Your program would disable the button when its command is not applicable at a given point in time.

> b.state(['disabled'])          # set the disabled flag

> b.state(['!disabled'])         # clear the disabled flag
>
> The full list of state flags available to themed widgets is: active, disabled, focus, pressed, selected, background, readonly, alternate, and invalid.

[Button State](https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/widgets.html#:%7E:text=or%20cancel%20button.-,Button%20State,-Buttons%20and%20many)